# Are ARMA models used to model the noise in a time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, noise

If we have a time series $y_t$ and we want to model it, is the following intuition about the ARMA model correct?

$$Y_t=f(\beta,t) + e_t $$ where $e_t \sim$ ARMA. So there is a decomposition of a deterministic part $f(\beta,t)$ and a stochastic part (the noise) which can be modelled by an ARMA process.

Comment: ARMA models are sometimes used this way. Alternatively, it may be that $Y_t$ is an ARMA.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for your reaction! But if $Y_t$ is an ARMA model itself it has to be stationary while many time series we observe in reality are not stationary (or contain seasonality, etc.)

Comment: It might be ARIMA instead, so trying in differences of the series might help. Alternatively, you could indeed suggest a model if differentiation does not work. For instance, you can use structural models with a polynomial trend and ARMA errors. I think the package **UComp** in R lets you adjust this type of models easily. For seasonality, you could use SARIMA models or structural models with a seasonal component. Both can be implemented in R.

Answer (score 1):

In most application cases your observed $Y_t$ is nonstationary but you can still model it using the generalized form of [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) such as [SARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average#Variations_and_extensions). If your $f(\beta,t)$ is simply a linear function of $t$ and the noise part $e_t$ is assumed to follow an ARMA process, then you can difference once your time series to model $Y_t$ as a ARIMA(p,d=1,q) model where d= is the order of difference. If $f(\beta,t)$ is a general polynomial trend then you can difference more times to arrive at a stationary ARMA model as shown in Brockwell et al's *Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting*. If $f(\beta,t)$ also contains seasonal trend then you can additionally do seasonal difference to arrive at SARIMA model which is a more generalized form of ARIMA and can account for both autoregressive lagged difference *and* seasonal difference mentioned above.

Of course In most applications you cannot even be sure your noise is really *generated* by a (stationary) ARMA process (white noise included since it's a special case of ARMA), albeit it's a common assumption in applications such as un-systematic measurement error or consecutive daily temperature series.